# Ordering Spreadsheet data cells by partial key

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have 4 columns in an excel file:

[image]

The two on the right have about 9000 rows.

The two on the left have about 14000.

The `THER_CLASS` column is the first 6 digits of the `key` column.

How would I order the left two columns by if the first 6 digits of the `key` matches `THER_CLASS`?

Edit:
If you look at the 1st row A you see 011000 this is associated with all of the key rows where the 1st 6 numbers are the same (011000):

[image]

I want row A and B copied for all accociated key/GPI numbers and then move on to the next one (012000):

[image]

Comment: I can't quite make out your question. Can you rephrase/ elaborate? Do you want to find which `THER_CLASS` matches the `Key`?

Comment: @loopo edited with more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to do a vlookup for this.

It allows you to look up one value in another range and get a  value some number of columns across. 
As in: lookup value X in column A and return the value that is 3columns across from that matching value.

In your case let's make the destination columns F & G, it would be something like:

Cell F2

```
=left(C2,6)
```

cell G2

```
=vlookup(F2,A:B,2,false)
```

Note:

- The list you're looking up (col A) has to be sorted in ascending order for this to work properly.
- That last parameter means only return a value for an exact match. Otherwise it will return the nearest lower value.
- You can lookup data on another sheet. I often do this to keep the main sheet clean.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the first 6 numbers for all data in the `GPI` column to show up on the `THER_CLASS` column.

If so then use the formula `=LEFT(cell of the text, how many character in text)`.

In your case, for cell A2, put the formula `=LEFT(C2,6)`.